# HTML Vs Markup Validation Service: attributes construct error

Tags: html, validation, hidden-field

why the Markup Validator says it has error in the html code below?

```
Line 287, Column 80: attributes construct error

…ion" value="set=1&amp;page=2" /><ul><li><a href="http://campusfaithhub.org/vie…
```

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcampusfaithhub.org%2Ffood%2Ffood-should&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&outline=1&group=0&No200=1&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.1

```
<div id="pagination">
    <!-- add this to fix IE whitespace bug. IE sees a space inside an empty div, and applies line-height to it. The div will then be expanded in IE6 (and older) to accommodate this space. There's your gap. Simplest solution is to make sure IE6 understands that the empty div really _is_ empty, by putting a comment inside it and make sure there's no line-break. -->
    <input type="hidden" class="last-pagination" value="set=1&amp;page=2" />
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://campusfaithhub.org/views/includes/layouts/items_comment.php?set=1&amp;page=1"class="current-pagination" rel="1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://campusfaithhub.org/views/includes/layouts/items_comment.php?set=1&amp;page=2" rel="1">2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--pagination-->
```

I have a hidden input field to store some info. If I take it out, it still is validated with errors! I can't find anything else to fix - can u see what I have done incorrectly? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: after viewing the source of your actual page, I see this problem...

```
<input type="hidden" class="last-pagination" value="set=1&amp;page=2" /><ul><li><a href="http://campusfaithhub.org/views/includes/layouts/items_comment.php?set=1&amp;page=1"class="current-pagination" rel="1">1</a></li><li><a href="http://campusfaithhub.org/views/includes/layouts/items_comment.php?set=1&amp;page=2" rel="1">2</a></li></ul></div>
```

Specifically: **page=1"class="current**

You need a space between the closing quote and opening attribute tag.

Comment: no im afraid there is no white space in between L and I at all as you can see it from the output. thanks.

Comment: now 'This document was successfully checked'. thank you! never knew that the space is so important! thanks! :-)